# Issues with Java Client<-->Server Socket

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

This is what I want to achieve:

There are client and server sockets. The client socket will send a message to the server (for instance `"add:2:3" to add 2 and 3`, etc). The server should response with an answer. When the answer arrives, the client can send additional message (like `"subtract:5:8" to subtract 5 from 8`), etc... Thus the client will send a message, then it will get a response, then it will send the next message and get a response, etc. Am sending the message from the command line.

This is what I have now but it is not working:

// Server code

```
public class MT extends Thread{

    private Socket sock;
    private BufferedReader rd;
    private OutputStreamWriter wr;

    private Client client;

    public MT(Socket sock) throws IOException {
        this.sock= sock;
        rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
        wr = new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
        wr.write("You are welcome"  + "\n");
        wr.flush();
    }

    public void run(){
        try{
            while(true){
                String command = reader.readLine(); 
                // Will process data here and then send results to client
                // At the moment i just want to send the message back to client
                wr.write(command + "\n"); // send results to client
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch(IOException ex){
            System.err.println("Problem reading data from client");
        }
    }

}


public class MyServio {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try(ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket()){

            server.bind(new InetSocketAddress("0.0.0.0", 4444));
            System.out.println("Listening...");

                try{
                    while(true){
                    Socket con = server.accept();

                    Thread a = new MT(con);
                    a.start();
                }
                }catch(IOException ex){
                    System.err.println("Problem...");
                }

        }catch(IOException ex){
            System.err.println("Server Issues");
        }
    }

}
```

// Client

For the client I decided to use two threads to read and write to the server

```
public class MyRead extends Thread{

    private BufferedReader r;

    public ReadFromServer(BufferedReader r){

            this.r = r;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
            StringBuilder m = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                while(true){
                    message.append(r.readLine());
                    System.out.println(m);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Problem in MyRead");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


    }

}




public class MyWrite extends Thread{

    private OutputStreamWriter w;
    Scanner sc;

    public WriteToServer(OutputStreamWriter w){
            this.w = w; 
            sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            while(true){ 
               System.out.print("Type message: ");
               String msg = sc.nextLine(); 
               w.write(msg + "\n");
               w.flush();
        }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Problem in MyWrite");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}




public class CSock {

    private OutputStreamWriter w;
    private BufferedReader r;

    public ClientSocket() {}

    public void do(){

        InetAddress ad = null;
        try {
            ad = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Error InetAddress");
        }
        try (Socket s = new Socket(addr, PORT)) {

            System.out.println("Server connecting...");


            StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();

            r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            w = new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream());

            message.append(r.readLine()); // reads the welcome message from server
            System.out.println(message); 

          // I start the read and write threads so that the client can read and write message to the server 
            ReadFromServer rd = new ReadFromServer(r);
            WriteToServer wt = new WriteToServer(w);
            rd.start();
            wt.start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("problem connecting to server");
        }
    }

}




public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        ClientSocket clientSocket = new ClientSocket();
        clientSocket.do();

    }

}
```

I start the server first, and then I start the client, but the client gives an exception:

```
Problem in MyRead
java.net.SocketException: socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at model.ReadFromServer.run(ReadFromServer.java:31)
```

The last line in the exception indicates that `message.append(reader.readLine());` in the code is the problem. I don't close sockets or input stream or output stream anywhere in my code, yet I get this exception.

Also get similar `socket closed` exception in the `MyWrite` class in the `run()` method in the following line `writer.flush();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You closed the socket and then continued to use it. The try-with-resource statement closed the socket; the two threads you started continued to use it.

Answer (score 1):

In the client on this line

```
try (Socket s = new Socket(addr, PORT)) {
```

You're telling the jvm that it should close the socket after executing the try statement.

This line is creating a reader from the output stream of the socket.

```
 r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
```

And this is creating a functionality that read from server.

```
ReadFromServer rd = new ReadFromServer(r);
```

ReadFromServer is a thread, and it's free to execute after the try-catch statement has finished. So when it execute `reader.readLine()` the socket is closed.